# rebar3 generate edoc for multiple apps

Tags: erlang, rebar3

If I have an OTP layout like this:

```
foo/
  - apps/
    - bar1/
      - src/
    - bar2
      - src/
```

How can I generate edoc for *both* `bar1` and `bar2`?

If I run:

```
rebar3 edoc
```

what I get is separate `.html` files in `bar1/doc` and `bar2/doc`, and none of the links between them work (i.e. export types are not linked correctly).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrote a rebar3 plugin called `medoc`, that will make sure docs generated by edoc are correctly linked and table of contents is updated:

https://github.com/drozzy/medoc

Run as:

```
rebar3 medoc
```

As for the standard `edoc`, this does not seem to be a feature yet. An intermediary solution is to use this in your rebar config:

```
{edoc_opts, [{dir, "doc"}]}
```

But this will not update the table of contents correctly (i.e. you'll only see one app's toc).

Answer (score 3):

This isn't supported by Rebar3 right now.

You can see [in the source code](https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/blob/master/src/rebar_prv_edoc.erl#L39-L46) that the `edoc` command just loops over each application with no state kept between them.

I'm not sure what it would take to connect them, but opening an issue on the Rebar3 repository to discuss it is probably the way to begin.